# How does Python manage int and long?

Tags: python, integer

Does anybody know how Python manage internally int and long types?

- Does it choose the right type dynamically?
- What is the limit for an int?
- I am using Python 2.6, Is is different with previous versions?

How should I understand the code below?

```
>>> print type(65535)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(65536*65536)
<type 'long'>
```

Update:

```
>>> print type(0x7fffffff)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(0x80000000)
<type 'long'>
```

Comment: Don't they just map to stdc types on the fly underneat in CPython?

Comment: Yeah, I think they do. I also suspect that everything is allocated on the heap, so when a number needs more precision they just `realloc` it all right. But I'm not quite sure, so I'll leave the answer to someone else.

Comment: You can also force python to use long variable with `var = 666L`

Comment: @Ignacio: **WRONG** A CPython `int` is a C `long` (default is signed) ... see `<CPython 2.X source>/Include/intobject.h`:
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;

In any case Python 2.x `int` allows negative numbers; a C `unsigned` just wouldn't cope.

Comment: PEP 237 discusses how under the hood Python is meant to make this all seemlessly the same.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`int` and `long` were "unified" [a few versions back](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/). Before that it was possible to overflow an int through math ops.

3.x has further advanced this by eliminating long altogether and only having int.

- **Python 2**: [`sys.maxint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) contains the maximum value a Python int can hold.

  - On a 64-bit Python 2.7, the size is 24 bytes. Check with `sys.getsizeof()`.
- **Python 3**: [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) contains the maximum size in bytes a Python int can be.

  - This will be gigabytes in 32 bits, and exabytes in 64 bits.
  - Such a large int would have a value similar to 8 to the power of `sys.maxsize`.

Comment: But Python3 calls this type 'int', even though it behaves more like 2.x's 'long'.

Comment: Comment by Ted : As mentioned below beware that casting something to int that is larger than maxint will still result in a long

 >>>type(int(sys.maxint+1))
<type 'long'>

Comment: sys.maxint will give you the largest 64bit integer (on my 64bit machine) a Long can be much larger that 64bits, just try "sys.maxint << 1000000"

Comment: In python3 it is sys.maxsize

Comment: sys.maxsize has nothing to do with integers. Python 3's sys.maxint was removed because there is no maximum size for an integer (Python 3's `int` is the same as Python 2's `long`).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. On my 64 bit Windows system, sys.maxint yields 2^31 -1.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson: You're running a 32-bit Python.

Comment: my sys.maxsize is 9223372036854775807, and it could still represent 9223372036854775807 + 1. I don't understand what sys.maxsize even means.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ You were confusing "max int" and "max size". Max size is an amount of bytes. On a 64-bit machine, your virtual memory has 64-bit wide addresses, but we'll leave 1 bit for sign and 1 value for null address, so that gives us 2**63 - 1 addressable bytes. That's 9223372036854775807. A python3 integer is not limited to the 64-bit hardware and can handle (in software) numbers that are bigger than 64-bit.

Comment: Thus if `maxint` was defined on Python 3, it would be `8**sys.maxsize`.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP cares about the size, just the range, but... I'm boggling that it takes 24 bytes to hold an int64.

Answer (score 25):

This [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) should help.

Bottom line is that you really shouldn't have to worry about it in python versions > 2.4

Comment: You have to worry about it if you have to call a int function in c with something that won't fit in int (i.e. a long). No amount of casting long->int will help. Happened to me just recently.

Comment: @Macke: This comment saved me, I assumed that int would do the trick, and was wondering why I was still getting a Jython exception.

Comment: @Macke Absolutely true. At the company I work at currently we have a Simulator written in Python that takes user input through Tkinter entries and sends the casted values via TCP/IP to a client (written in C/C++) that mimics an embedded system. Imagine what happens when you insert 100000000000000000000000 in your Python-based Entry... :P

Answer (score 14):

Python 2 will automatically set the type based on the size of the value. A guide of max values can be found below.

The Max value of the default Int in Python 2 is 65535, anything above that will be a long

For example:

```
>> print type(65535)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(65536*65536)
<type 'long'>
```

In Python 3 the long datatype has been removed and all integer values are handled by the Int class. The default size of Int will depend on your CPU architecture.

For example:

- 32 bit systems the default datatype for integers will be 'Int32'
- 64 bit systems the default datatype for integers will be 'Int64'

The min/max values of each type can be found below:

- Int8: [-128,127]
- Int16: [-32768,32767]
- Int32: [-2147483648,2147483647]
- Int64: [-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807]
- Int128: [-170141183460469231731687303715884105728,170141183460469231731687303715884105727]
- UInt8: [0,255]
- UInt16: [0,65535]
- UInt32: [0,4294967295]
- UInt64: [0,18446744073709551615]
- UInt128: [0,340282366920938463463374607431768211455]

If the size of your Int exceeds the limits mentioned above, python will automatically change it's type and allocate more memory to handle this increase in min/max values. Where in Python 2, it would convert into 'long', it now just converts into the next size of Int.

Example: If you are using a 32 bit operating system, your max value of an Int will be 2147483647 by default. If a value of 2147483648 or more is assigned, the type will be changed to Int64.

There are different ways to check the size of the int and it's memory allocation.
Note: In Python 3, using the built-in type() method will always return `<class 'int'>` no matter what size Int you are using.

Comment: This is the most detailed answer, but I'm not sure it's detailed enough for Python 3 (while Python 2 info can just be deleted). What about the arbitrary-length long? What about using the C-style types directly, eg for porting C code or low-level programming?

Comment: The maximum value of the default int in Python 2 is not 65535 on my typical 64 bit installation (and Python 2's behavior is still of interest to some of us):
`mad@shuttle:~$ python --version; python -c 'print(type(0x7FFFffffFFFFffff))'
Python 2.7.16
<type 'int'>
mad@shuttle:~$ `

Comment: if Int64 is default, Int8/Int16/Int32 will never be used because  Int64 is already larger than them, when Int8/Int16/Int32 are used internally?

Answer (score 6):

On my machine:

```
>>> print type(1<<30)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(1<<31)
<type 'long'>
>>> print type(0x7FFFFFFF)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(0x7FFFFFFF+1)
<type 'long'>
```

Python uses ints (32 bit signed integers, I don't know if they are C ints under the hood or not) for values that fit into 32 bit, but automatically switches to longs (arbitrarily large number of bits - i.e. bignums)  for anything larger. I'm guessing this speeds things up for smaller values while avoiding any overflows with a seamless transition to bignums.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting.  On my 64-bit (i7 Ubuntu) box:

```
>>> print type(0x7FFFFFFF)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(0x7FFFFFFF+1)
<type 'int'>
```

Guess it steps up to 64 bit ints on a larger machine.

Comment: Python uses the larger integer type avaiable for the machine.
SO usually on 32-bit machines int will have 32bit size, while on 64 bit-machines it will have 64 bit size.
But there could be 32-bit architectures defining 64 bit integers, in that case python would use the 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 4):

Python 2.7.9 auto promotes numbers.
For a case where one is unsure to use int() or long().

```
>>> a = int("123")
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = int("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
>>> type(a)
<type 'long'>
```

Answer (score 2):

From python 3.x, the unified integer libraries are even more smarter than older versions. On my (i7 Ubuntu) box I got the following,

```
>>> type(math.factorial(30))
<class 'int'>
```

For implementation details refer `Include/longintrepr.h, Objects/longobject.c and Modules/mathmodule.c` files. The last file is a dynamic module (compiled to an so file). The code is well commented to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It manages them because `int` and `long` are sibling class definitions.  They have appropriate methods for +, -, *, /, etc., that will produce results of the appropriate class.

For example

```
>>> a=1<<30
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> b=a*2
>>> type(b)
<type 'long'>
```

In this case, the class `int` has a `__mul__` method (the one that implements *) which creates a `long` result when required.

Answer (score 0):

Just to continue to all the answers that were given here, especially @James Lanes

the size of the integer type can be expressed by this formula:

total range =  (2 ^ bit system)

lower limit = -(2 ^ bit system)*0.5
upper limit =  ((2 ^ bit system)*0.5) - 1