# Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?

Tags: python, mysql

My question is why do a MySQL row's integer values have an 'L' suffix? Here are the details:

The following dictionary -- artificially formatted here for ease of display --

```
{'estimated': '', 
 'suffix': '', 
 'typeofread': 'g', 
  'acct_no': 901001000L, 
  'counter': 0, 
  'time_billed': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 9, 5, 33), 
  'date_read': datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 13, 23, 19, 45), 
  'reading': 3018L, 
  'meter_num': '26174200'}
```

is comprised of a MySQL database table's columns zipped with the result of reading once from the table.

I can remove the 'L' by passing these values into int(), so if that dictionary were in a variable named snapped_read, I could do this:

`int(snapped_read['reading'])` and `3018L` would change to `3018`.

I'm just curious as to why integers show up this way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Because in versions of Python before Python 3, long integer literals were indicated with an `l` or `L` suffix. In Python 3, `int`s and `long`s have been merged into just `int`, which functions pretty much like `long` used to.

Do note that, technically, Python( 2)'s `int` was equivalent to C's `long`, while Python's `long` was more like a `BigNumber`-type thing with unlimited precision (which is now the case for Python 3's `int` type.)

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: Side note: MySQLdb convert ALL integer types to long type on Python 2.x

Comment: Interesting to know. It looks like only `BIGINT` would require that, though, so I'm guessing it's for consistency in terms of the Python interface. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Yeah, don't know why, but even `TINYINT` columns got converted to long type... Needs further investigation, but I also think it's due to the  Python's database interface API.

Answer (score 13):

`L` is for the `long` data type.

For example,

```
age = 24 # int
bankBalance = 20000005L # long
```

Comment: You need a `long` to contain your bank balance?  Shouldn't you be sipping lemonade by a pool somwhere?  What are you doing answering questions on SO? (+1) -- although you might want to change your comments from `//` to `#`.

Comment: Sorry @mgilson I am a PHP guy :)

Comment: In Python you code just `age = 24` and `bankBalance = 20000005L`, no type definitions neither semicolons to end statements. :)

Comment: I wish I needed a long to keep my bank balance!! **:D**

Answer (score 8):

Because they're not exactly integers, they are 'longs'.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric

They usually don't offer too much trouble, though

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=long(1)
>>> a
1
>>> b
1L
>>> a==b
True
```

Other stackoverflow question about this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long)