# all points within distance

Tags: python, spatial-query

I´m really desperate. 
What I wanna do ist:
I have a list of 2d points

```
    L=[(22.37, 29.48), (20.50, 30.28), (20.50, 30.28), (20.77, 30.01), (20.77, 30.01), (21.04, 29.74), (21.04, 29.74), (22.58, 29.44), (22.78, 29.19), (23.11, 28.87)]
```

(my list has 30000 tuples (xn,yn)).
Now I want all points  within distance dmax (from every point).
Therefor I used  scipy.spatial.KDTree() and query_ball_point.

```
    import scipy.spatial
    tree = scipy.spatial.KDTree(XY)
    k=np.array(tree.query_ball_tree(tree, dmax))
```

For my first point I get

```
    array([ [ 12475L, 12476L, 15081L, 15082L, 15083L, 22380L, 22381L, 22562L, 22379L, 12469L, 12470L, 13469L, 13470L, 13471L, 13472L, 15084L, 15085L, 15086L, 15087L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 13468L, 22374L, 22375L, 22376L, 22377L, 22378L, 22557L, 22558L, 22559L, 22560L, 22561L, 23091L, 22503L, 22504L, 22505L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L,...]])
```

Why there are these 'L's??
How can I remove these?

Thanks for help!

Comment: No need to do anything.They are Long integers.

Answer (score 4):

They're long integers. It's not hard to find stuff like this yourself, try googling for 'python numbers with L' and you would find similar questions like [Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to do anything.They are Long integers.Your calculations are fine with being them.

Comment: Yes, L means "long integer".

Comment: But isn´t there a problem if I wonna work with these indices, eg compare them with the indices of my list L?

Answer (score 0):

The L won't have any effect as others have pointed out, you will *still* be able to use those numbers to access an array by index - why don't you just try it?. For more information you should read about [Integers in computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_integer).