# Python : Do not include "L" at the end of the outcome for : randint(100000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999)

Tags: python, python-2.7

so far this is what i found:

```
 from random import randint
 randint(100000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999)
```

the output is:

```
922106555361958347898L
```

but i do not want that L there..

i can only use this as an int if there is no "L" there at the end of it.

**UPDATE**

would it be a better idea to generate two small numbers and then combine them if the goal is to simply have a random number that is 30 digits long ?

Comment: Don't print the `repr()` of the value and you're fine. What are you doing with that value?

Comment: Any integer outside the range of +/-2**31 won't fit in small integer object, and your numbers are much larger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix)

Comment: @Schorsch: I'm not sure whether it's a dup or not. Clearly the two askers had similar confusion, but I'm not sure the answers there would help here. (But if nothing else, it _definitely_ deserves to appear in the Linked questions list…)

Comment: "would it be a better idea to generate two small numbers and then combine them if the goal is to simply have a random number that is 30 digits long ?" No. A random number that's 30 digits long is going to be a `long`, no matter how you create it, because you can't fit 30 digits in an `int`. And there's nothing wrong with that. Trying to combine two smaller numbers is just going to add complexity, inefficiency, and an easy place for bugs to slip in, for no benefit.

Comment: Just use `str(randint(100000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999))` to output the value.

Comment: @abarnert it is not an exact duplicate. but the question where the `L` comes from and why it is there is answered in the other question.

Comment: @user4018347: If your goal is to insert it into MySQL… well, IIRC, the two most popular MySQL libraries for Python 2.x convert all integer values into `long` anwyay, even if they're small enough to fit in an `int`, so your problem is even more not a problem.

Comment: Actually, scratch that; [`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) apparently converts signed `INTEGER`, `INT`, and smaller types into `int`, and anything larger or unsigned into `long`.  But that doesn't matter; it'll still take `long` values for `TINYINT` columns and `int` values for `BIGINT` columns without complaint. So the point still stands: you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @abarnert sorry, what I meant was either `2**31 - 1` or to specify that the range was non-inclusive of the endpoints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason there's an `L` there is because this is too large to fit into an `int`,* so it's a `long`. See [Numeric Types — `int`, `long`, `float`, `complex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) in the docs for more details.

---

So, why do you get that `L`, and how do you get rid of it?

Python has two different ways to turn a value into a string representation:

- [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) either returns the canonical source-code representation, or something like `<__main__.Eggs at 0x10fbd8908>`).
- [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-str) returns a human-friendly representation.

For example, for strings, `str('abc')` is `abc`, while `repr('abc')` is `'abc'`.

And for longs, `str(1L)` is `1`, while `repr(1L)` is `1L`.

---

When you just type an expression at the interactive prompt, it uses `repr`. But when you use the `print` command, it uses `str`. So, if you want to see the value without the `L`, just `print` it:

```
print randint(100000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999)
```

If you want to, e.g., save the string in a variable or write it to a file, you have to call `str` explicitly.

But if you just want to use it as a number, you don't have to worry about this at all; it's a number, and `int` and `long` values can be intermixed freely (as of Python 2.3 or so).

And if you're trying to store it in a MySQL database, whichever MySQL interface you use won't care whether you're giving it `int` values or `long`, as long as they fit into the column type.**

---

Or you could upgrade to Python 3.x, where there is no separate `long` type anymore (all integers are `int`, no matter how big) and no `L` suffix.

---

<sub>* The exact cutoff isn't documented anywhere, but at least for CPython, it's whatever fits into a C `long` on your platform. So, on most 64-bit platforms, the max value is (1<<63)-1; on the other 64-bit platforms, and all 32-bit platforms, it's (1<<31)-1. You can see for yourself on your platform by printing `sys.maxint`. At any rate, your number takes 70 bits, so unless someone ports Python 2.x to a platform with 128-bit C `long`s, it won't fit.</sub>

<sub>** Note that your values are too big to fit into even a MySQL [`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html), so you're going to be using either [`DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html). Depending on which interface you're using, and how you've set things up, you may have to convert to and from strings manually. But you can do that with the `str` and `int` functions, without worrying about which values fit into the `int` type and which don't.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the interactive prompt, explicitly `print` the value. The `repr` of the value has an L, but the `str` of the value doesn't.

```
>>> 922106555361958347898
922106555361958347898L
>>> print 922106555361958347898
922106555361958347898
```

Answer (score 0):

The output in the REPL has an `L` suffixed; if you print the value, it is not displayed.

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> print randint(100000000000000000000, 999999999999999999999)
106315199286113607384
>>>
```