# Making OrderedDict out of Lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, pivot-table, ordereddictionary

I am trying to modify my code so that it will work over different time spans. I want my variable days_dict to look like months_dict.

I have this variable called months_dict which works very well. I made it using these lines of code

```
graphmonths = [pivot_table[(m)].astype(float).values for m in range(1, 13)]
names = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov", "Dec"]
months_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(names, graphmonths)))
```

It looks like this

```
months_dict
Out[86]: 
OrderedDict([('Jan', array([ 17.,   4.,  11.,  12.,  13.,   6.,   9.,   7.,   8.,   7.,   4.,
         3.,   5.,   3.,   4.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   3.,   4.,  10.,   5.,
         8.,   5.,   3.,   4.,   9.,   4.,   2.,   2.])), ('Feb', array([ 30.,  11.,   8.,  11.,  10.,  10.,   1.,   8.,   3.,   5.,   5.,
        11.,   6.,   8.,   3.,   5.,   2.,   5.,  15.,   2.,   3.,   8.,
         6.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   9.,   6.,  11.,   1.])), ('Mar', array([ 29.,  13.,  25.,   6.,   7.,  11.,   2.,   9.,   9.,   5.,   4.,
         7.,  12.,   5.,   5.,   8.,   8.,   5.,  13.,   6.,   8.,   3.,
         7.,   5.,  10.,   5.,   6.,   4.,   3.,   4.])), ('Apr', array([ 39.,  22.,  24.,  23.,  14.,   8.,  20.,   7.,   8.,   3.,   6.,
         7.,   6.,   6.,   6.,   3.,  15.,   8.,   4.,   1.,   5.,   2.,
         4.,   7.,   2.,   4.,   6.,   3.,   5.,   0.])), ('May', array([ 15.,  34.,   7.,  11.,   6.,   3.,   6.,  11.,   9.,   3.,   5.,
         5.,  10.,   1.,   5.,   4.,   2.,   4.,   5.,   5.,   2.,   3.,
        13.,   9.,   4.,   7.,   5.,   3.,   5.,   0.])), ('Jun', array([ 27.,  27.,  13.,  11.,   8.,   4.,   7.,   4.,   7.,   7.,   4.,
         9.,   6.,   4.,   6.,   4.,   7.,   9.,   1.,   3.,   2.,  11.,
         8.,   1.,   4.,   4.,   5.,   1.,   3.,  10.])), ('Jul', array([ 22.,  30.,  24.,   9.,   5.,  10.,   6.,   3.,   5.,   9.,  12.,
         6.,   4.,   6.,   5.,  10.,   6.,   7.,   1.,   9.,   2.,   6.,
         0.,   8.,   6.,   2.,   3.,   6.,   5.,   9.])), ('Aug', array([ 12.,  18.,   0.,   4.,  10.,   8.,   4.,   3.,   7.,   7.,  14.,
         3.,   5.,  10.,   5.,   7.,   6.,   2.,   0.,   8.,  20.,  10.,
         1.,   5.,   7.,   8.,   3.,   0.,   5.,  12.])), ('Sep', array([ 36.,  29.,  21.,   6.,  13.,  11.,   6.,   6.,   6.,  11.,   5.,
         6.,   3.,   6.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   5.,   7.,   8.,   2.,   3.,
         1.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   3.,   3.,  10.,   7.])), ('Oct', array([ 21.,  31.,  12.,  11.,   8.,  11.,   6.,   5.,   9.,   6.,   8.,
         5.,   4.,   4.,   7.,   4.,   1.,   6.,   9.,   3.,   5.,   7.,
         6.,   7.,   6.,   6.,   3.,   4.,   4.,   8.])), ('Nov', array([ 18.,  17.,  12.,   5.,  12.,  18.,  12.,   8.,   3.,  10.,   2.,
         3.,   9.,   4.,  12.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   2.,   8.,   4.,   5.,
         4.,   3.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  21.,   3.,   3.])), ('Dec', array([ 15.,  14.,  17.,  10.,  11.,  14.,   7.,  11.,   5.,   3.,   6.,
         9.,   3.,  15.,   9.,  11.,   5.,   7.,   5.,   7.,   1.,   1.,
         4.,   1.,   7.,   7.,   3.,   4.,   2.,   2.]))])
```

Now I am trying to do the same but for a month. So I have

```
Days = pivot_table.columns[1:].tolist()
```

this gives

```
Days
Out[80]: 
[1L,
 2L,
 3L,
 4L,
 5L,
 6L,
 7L,
 8L,
 9L,
 10L,
 11L,
 12L,
 13L,
 14L,
 15L,
 16L,
 17L,
 18L,
 19L,
 20L,
 21L,
 22L,
 23L,
 24L,
 25L,
 26L,
 27L,
 28L,
 29L,
 30L]
```

Then I have

```
graphdays = [pivot_table[(m)].astype(float).values for m in range(1, len(Days)+1)]
days_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(Days, graphdays)
```

but days_dict looks like this:

```
days_dict
Out[73]: 
OrderedDict([(1L, array([ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (2L, array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (3L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (4L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (5L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (6L, array([ 1.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  0.])), (7L, array([ 2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  2.,  0.])), (8L, array([ 9.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (9L, array([ 1.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (10L, array([ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (11L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (12L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (13L, array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (14L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (15L, array([  0.,   2.,  10.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   0.,   1.,   1.,
         3.,   0.,   2.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   2.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.])), (16L, array([ 0.,  4.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (17L, array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (18L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (19L, array([ 4.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (20L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (21L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (22L, array([ 2.,  1.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  0.])), (23L, array([ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  3.,  0.,  1.])), (24L, array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  2.])), (25L, array([ 1.,  4.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  0.,
        2.,  0.,  0.,  2.])), (26L, array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (27L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (28L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])), (29L, array([ 2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  0.])), (30L, array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]))])
```

With 'L's in the code.

What are these 'L's? How can I remove them so that this code will work the same as with months_dict?

Comment: I imagine it means you have a `long`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham any idea how to get rid of it to make the two dicts match?

Comment: can you add a sample of your df?

Comment: @Jenrryb, can you add a bit of the original df itself so I can copy/paste and run the code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Here is some mock data https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2010jiiuve6hy9/MOCK_DATA%20%281%29.csv?dl=0

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I also added the code leading up to what I originally posted to make it easier to copy paste.

Comment: what should `result.columns = ['Month', 'CompanyName', 'NumberCalls']` actually be?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Everything with 'Month' changes to 'Day' in the new code.

Comment: Are you missing some column names? There are 7 in the original df

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am only using two columns for the code, the CompanyName and the recvd_dttm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured out how to make it work. First I had to make a list of Days. I took this from my dataframe. Then I used

```
graphdays = [pivot_table[(m)].astype(float).values for m in range(1, len(Days)+1)]
days_dict = OrderedDict(list(zip(Days, graphdays)))
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

L means long integer ([Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix)). Long integers and regular integers were merged in Python 3, so you can get rid of them by switching to Python 3. I do not think you have to worry about them, however.

Comment: Ah. What if I want to stay with Python 2.7? It seems like people say to ignore them, but in my case the months_dict is working and the days_dict is not, and since that's the only difference I see, I feel like that's the problem.