# Python PostGreSQL query doesn't return plain number

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm running a PostGreSQL query and when I print it, this is returned: `[{'sum': 117L}]`

Here is the code itself:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(length) FROM carmileage")
totalLength = cursor.fetchall()
print totalLength
```

How would I format this into a number without the (what appears to be) surrounding JSON?

Comment: Also see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate through your resultset. Cursors pass rows in SQL select queries into Python lists:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(length) FROM carmileage")
totalLength = cursor.fetchall()

for row in totalLength:
    print(row)
```

Comment: I found the solution that worked best for me was to use `cursor.fetchone()['sum']`