# retriveing data from MySQL into Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have the following code:

I have a query which gives me result from MySQL:

```
import MySQLdb
db_mysql=MySQLdb.Connect(user=...,passwd=...,db=..., host=...)
cur = db_mysql.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute ("""SELECT X,Y,Z FROM tab_a""")
for row in crs.fetchall () :
     do things...
```

X is defined in MySql as: `bigint(20) unsigned` .

In python it shows the number with l suffix : `1445l`

according to this [Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) it's a normal behavior for python 2.7

The thing is that I need to use X value in other queries so I saved it: `save_x = str(row["X"])`
This auto remove the `l` suffix.

Now, if I do:

```
cur.execute ("""SELECT A FROM tablx where id='%s'""")%save_x
```

Doesn't work. it says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'str'

How can I make it work?
I know that it doesn't work beacsue i'm comparing long with string, but if I leave it as a number it stays with L suffix and this also doesn't work.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with the old syntax, but try:

```
cur.execute ("SELECT A FROM tablx where id='{save_x}'".format(save_x=save_x))
```

and report whether it helped.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem might be coming from the fact that your are not formatting the query argument but your are trying to format the function/method call itself.

Try to change this instruction :

```
cur.execute ("""SELECT A FROM tablx where id='%s'""")%save_x
```

into :

```
cur.execute("""SELECT A FROM tablx WHERE id='%s'"""%save_x)
```

By the way, you should take care about the output string. If save_x == 1, with the '%s' you will get something like:

```
"SELECT A FROM tblx WHERE id='1'"
```

This might return you an error from the db if the awaited type is a long or an int.