# Python numpy shape outputs L

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I just installed anaconda with python version 2.7 and am trying out the [tutorial](https://github.com/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial). However, the function

`array.shape`

gives me (6L,6L). What does the L mean ? I read that it means I am using an older version of python ? How can that be ? I am using windows with zero knowledge on command line so please no command line suggestions.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix

Comment: Thanks ! I guess i shouldn't bother with the feature. Could be useful one day