# How to recursively search the maximum in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm quite new to python and algorithm and I encountered a question which is defined as follows:

Suppose that you are given a python list `l` of size `n` which contains only numbers. We index `l` from 0 to `n-1`. Further, we suppose that there exists an index `k ∈ {1, ..., n-2}` such that

- for all `i ∈ {0, ..., k-1}`, `l[i] < l[i+1]`
- for all `i ∈ {k, ..., n-2}`, `l[i] > l[i+1]`

In other words, l is unimodal. An example with `k=3` is given below:

> l = [-5, 8, 12, **15**, 13, 12, 10, 5, 1, 0, -2]

I can easily implement it using an iterative approach:

```
def findK(l):
    k = 0
    while l[k] < l[k + 1]:
        k += 1
    return k
```

But how can I do it using a recursive way which is ***O(logn)***?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the maximum element with a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525085/finding-the-maximum-element-with-a-recursive-function)

Comment: @RamanMishra Not exactly since the nature of the array is different and he needs in O(log(n)).

Comment: @RamanMishra welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum/minimum of a unimodal function can be obtained by using the concept of **Ternary Search**

```
def ternarySearch(f, left, right, absolutePrecision):
    '''
    left and right are the current bounds; 
    the maximum is between them
    '''
    if abs(right - left) < absolutePrecision:
        return (left + right)/2

    leftThird = (2*left + right)/3
    rightThird = (left + 2*right)/3

    if f(leftThird) < f(rightThird):
        return ternarySearch(f, leftThird, right, absolutePrecision) 
    else:
        return ternarySearch(f, left, rightThird, absolutePrecision)
```

The overall complexity of the solution is O(log<sub>3</sub>N). You can learn more about it from https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/searching/ternary-search/tutorial/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Comment: Thanks this is a quite new but useful concept to me!

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm**

- You can use binary search to do this(if you wish to).
- If we come across a pattern of `b-1 < b < b+1` where `b` was our middle element, then surely the highest element is to the right side of the array.
- If we come across a pattern of `b-1 > b > b+1` where `b` was our middle element, then surely the highest element is to the left side of the array.
- If we come across a pattern of `b-1 < b > b+1` where `b` was our middle element, then this `b` is our answer.

**CODE:**

```
mid = 0,low=0,high = arr.size-1
while low <= high: 
    mid = low + (high - low) / 2
    if arr[mid] > arr[mid-1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]:
        return arr[mid]
    else if arr[mid] < arr[mid-1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]:
        high = mid - 1
    else 
        low = mid + 1
```

Time complexity is **O(log<sub>2</sub>n)**. But, as mentioned by @nellex in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130064/4964822), **ternary search** provides a better performance.

Comment: Sorry for the fact that it isn't recursive though

Comment: @AlexWang Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The recursive version of your code would be

```
def max_modal(list, start=0):
    If start < len(list):
        If list[start]>list[start+1]:
            Return list[start]
        Else:
            Return max_modal(list,start=start+1)
     Else:
         Return list[start]
```

However in a interpreter language this Schild be a lot slower than the iterative way