# Fetch multiple values from database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I get from my DB the following return, when I use the sql command `SELECT DISTINCT RezeptID
FROM Rezepte;`:

```
((1L,), (13L,), (14L,), (15L,))
```

Now I want to work with this values. Normally I use for single values something like this:

```
a=cursor.execute(sql_command)
(a, )=cursor.fetchone()
```

But then I get of course only the first value, the "1" back.
How can I work with all these values? It would be optimal when I can put all these values in a array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursor can be used as an iterator to iterate over rows in the result set. To get the first value from each row try this:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
values = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

Comment: Okay, that works so far but the all the values in the list have an L behind the value. So the list looks so now : ´[1L, 13L, 14L, 15L]´

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11764713/244297 Generally, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: So what? That has no impact on anything.

Comment: Ah, okay now I got it. This L only shows that this are long values^^

Answer (score 0):

cursor.fetchall() if you are using sqlalchemy.

Comment: Yes, but when I use ´(a,b,c,d, )=cursor.fetchall()´ I get values like (1L, ) with the datatype tuple