# 'L' stands for count query in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I did a normal count query for PostgreSQL. I am calling it from python.
The query goes like:

```
SELECT COUNT(CAST(cust_ID AS int)),CAST(cust_ID AS int) 
       FROM OF_table 
       GROUP BY CAST(cust_ID AS int) 
       ORDER BY CAST(cust_ID AS int)
```

The output has the value like:

> 245L 10

Can someone tell me if the 'L' means lines? I do not understand the
 unit 'L'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 there was a distinction between integers and long integers. The L means 245 is represented internally as a long integer.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11764774/871910) for more info.

You should really upgrade to Python 3. For many reasons besides this L.