# pyglet.gl syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, pyglet, python-3.3

I have just started to attempt to use the alpha version of pyglet (1.2alpha1) and creating a window i.e.

```
win = pyglet.window.Window()
```

causes a syntax error in the pyglet.window on line 133, which is:

```
from pyglet.gl import gl_info
```

to be honest... I have no idea what is even going on here because from x import y is valid syntax and I am completely new to pyglet and have only very very basic knowledge of openGL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer, it turns out that a load of python 2.x code had made it through, things like

```
print 'string'
```

and badly defined imports such as

```
from base import (loads of modules here)
```

where it should have been

```
from pyglet.gl.base import (aforementioned modules)
```

there have been a whole load of these problems, and as such i have given up for now (due to some number followed by an L (I have no experience with python 2.x so i have no idea what the 3.x equivalent is))

Comment: The use of `L` with an integer value just indicates that it's a long integer in Python 2.x. See [this doc page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric) for more specific info.

Comment: Thanks, I guess because 3.x doesn't use longs, it should be safe to remove them

Comment: Mercifully, Python 3 has made all ints longs, so yeah, you should be okay to remove them. I'm guessing they were only there in the first place for backward-compatibility purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long