# Python Syntax Error on Bit Literal

Tags: python

I have inherited this python program and, being sort of a noob with bits and such I can't figure out what the problem is. I am getting a syntax error on the first line of the following function:

```
def tileKey(self, z, x, y):
    zBits = z & 0xFFL
    #  8bits, 256 levels. normally [0,21]
    xBits = x & 0xFFFFFFFL
    #  28 bits
    yBits = y & 0xFFFFFFFL
    #  28 bits
    key = (zBits << 56) | (xBits << 28) | (yBits << 0)
    #  return the key value integer 720576213915009588
    return key
```

Comment: also, if you are not in a class, omit the `self` argument

Comment: Please edit your post to include the full traceback/error-message. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, the cutting pasting error, whitespace is corrected. Also this is inside a class, hence the self arg.

Comment: what actually is 0xFFL for a number?
There is no `L` in hex?!

Comment: @cIph3r `L` stands for `Long` (unrelated but interesting → [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2104947/1376657)).

Comment: ahh ok, I use python3.2, the `L` does not exist here anymore

Comment: @cIph3r I've already taken a guess that is the error :) Short of confirmation though - we're still waiting to see what the real error message is

Comment: I checked Jon Clements Answer, thanks to everybody. I was running it in the GUI that came with Python on windows, IDLE. So it was literally just a message box that said "syntax error." Thanks again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.x, then you can't use the 'L' suffix anymore as it's no longer required and not part of the syntax:

```
yBits = y & 0xFFFFFFFL
Original exception was:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0xFFL
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: so... just remove the '`L`'?

Comment: @cryanbhu yup - that's the one...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the wrong indentation, you have to indent body of the function. Your function should be indented like this:

```
def tileKey(self, z, x, y):
    zBits = z & 0xFFL
    #  8bits, 256 levels. normally [0,21]
    xBits = x & 0xFFFFFFFL
    #  28 bits
    yBits = y & 0xFFFFFFFL
    #  28 bits
    key = (zBits << 56) | (xBits << 28) | (yBits << 0)
    #  return the key value integer 720576213915009588
    return key
```

It looks like it is a method in a class, so the whole definition of the method should be indented after the line with  `class` keyword, for example:

```
class YourClass:
    def tileKey(self, z, x, y):
        zBits = z & 0xFFL
        #  8bits, 256 levels. normally [0,21]
        xBits = x & 0xFFFFFFFL
        #  28 bits
        yBits = y & 0xFFFFFFFL
        #  28 bits
        key = (zBits << 56) | (xBits << 28) | (yBits << 0)
        #  return the key value integer 720576213915009588
        return key
```

Comment: sorry my bad, the indentation was corrrect, the cutting and pasting wasn't, should be fixed now.

Comment: So what is the error message you get?