# How does the Python interpreter convert an int to a long?

Tags: python, type-conversion

What exactly happens when an int is converted to a long?

For example:

```
a = sys.maxint-1
a = a+2
```

What happened in the statement of  `a = a + 2`?

How does the Python interpreter handle the overflow ?

Answer (score 4):

Lets [read the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5d99042bd40f/Objects/intobject.c#l471) (I have python2.7.3 on my machine):

Here's where the addition takes place (as far as I can tell):

```
static PyObject *
int_add(PyIntObject *v, PyIntObject *w)
{
    register long a, b, x;
    CONVERT_TO_LONG(v, a);
    CONVERT_TO_LONG(w, b);
    /* casts in the line below avoid undefined behaviour on overflow */
    x = (long)((unsigned long)a + b);
    if ((x^a) >= 0 || (x^b) >= 0)
        return PyInt_FromLong(x);
    return PyLong_Type.tp_as_number->nb_add((PyObject *)v, (PyObject *)w);
}
```

So far, not too bad -- We get C `long` types from the python integer types in the `CONVERT_TO_LONG` macro.  Then they do an addition.  Notice how they pull some interesting tricks with casting the various longs in order to detect overflow.*  If no overflow is detected, they convert the C `long` back into a python object and return it.  If there is an overflow, you can see that they then try the addition again -- This time, using the python `long` type (`PyLong_Type`).

If you look at `int_sub`, you'll see that it's pretty much the same thing (with slightly different bit trickery to detect underflow).  `int_mul` appears to be a little more complicated, and comes with a nice big block comment.  Really, the code is littered with comments about how they deal with the overflow/underflow in different situations.  It's pretty informative.

- I'm a bit too tired right now to unravel it, but if you do, feel free to leave a comment (or just edit).

Answer (score 3):

First,

> int and long were "unified" a few versions back. Before that it was possible to overflow an int through math ops.
>
> 3.x has further advanced this by eliminating int altogether and only having long.

Based on question here, [How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long)

Also, there is no longer a limit on `integers` according to  http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

> The sys.maxint constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit
>   to the value of integers. However, sys.maxsize can be used as an
>   integer larger than any practical list or string index. It conforms to
>   the implementation’s “natural” integer size and is typically the same
>   as sys.maxint in previous releases on the same platform (assuming the
>   same build options).

**Basically**:

*Python seamlessly converts a number that becomes too large for an integer to a long.*

Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref5.html)