# Why does this function return a long rather than an int?

Tags: python, types, int, long-integer, return-type

I've defined a function that takes as an input a positive integer and returns the sum of its digits:

```
def digitSum(n):
    exp = 0
    digitSum = 0
    while n%(10**exp) != n:
        digitSum += (n%(10**(exp+1))-n%(10**(exp)))/(10**exp)
        exp += 1
    return digitSum
```

It seems that if n < 10**9, then digitSum returns an int and returns a long otherwise. If I want it to always return an int, I could have it return int(digitSum) rather than digitSum, so that is not the issue. My question is why does this return a long in the first place?

Comment: Why do you care? In Python 3 `long` is gone anyway and replaced by a smarter `int`... And fyi, I'd rewrite your function like this: `sum(map(int, str(n)))` - more readable and probably also faster.

Comment: I was unaware of the map function. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python <3 automatically converts `int` to an `long` if the number gets too big.
You can read more about it here.

[How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long)

(this automatic conversion is one of the reasons python is more memory consuming and slower than lets say C/C++ but that is another discussion)

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = sys.maxint             # set a variable to your systems maximum integer
>>> print type(x)
<type 'int'>                   # type is then set to int
>>> x += 1                     # if you increase it, it gets converted into long
>>> print type(x)
<type 'long'>
```

Comment: To see how big is "too big": `sys.maxint`

Comment: So the "problem" was that when it computed n%(10**(exp+1)) for the last time, the divisor was long.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 differentiates between integers that can be stored in the machine's underlying `int` type (`int`) and arbitrary-precision integers that are implemented in the language (`long`). You can't force your function to return an `int` (without introducing overflow errors, anyway), since Python 2 automatically creates a `long` object when the value is too large to fit in an `int`.

In Python 3, the distinction was removed from the Python level: all values are `int`s, regardless of magnitude, and any finer distinction is an implementation detail of the builtin `int` type.