# Google Appengine Long to Int

Tags: google-app-engine

When I input the variable a

```
a = int(1388620800)*1000
```

(of course) this variable is returned

```
1388620800000
```

But in the Google Appengine Server, this variable is changed by https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#int

```
1388620800000L
```

How to convert 1388620800000L to int type in Appengine?

**EDIT**

I will print this number for JSON. In the local Python2.7, the variable 'a' is just integer. But in the appengine server, the variable 'a' has string 'L'. I solved it using str() and .replace('L',''), but I wonder how to solve it with changing number type.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an App Engine question.

In Python, longs and ints are exactly equivalent and there is no reason you would ever need to convert from one to another.

**Edit**

Your explanation does not make sense either, unfortunately. JSON has no long type, and the Python `json` library makes no distinction between longs and ints:

```
>>> json.dumps(1388620800000L)
'1388620800000'
>>> json.dumps(1388620800000)
'1388620800000'
```

As you can see, they are treated exactly the same.

Comment: This is App Engine question. When you enter the variable a = int(1388620800)*1000, a is int in python2.7. But in the appengine server, a is Long type.

Comment: But *there is no difference*. Why do you care? Why do you think you need to convert it?

Comment: Sorry for my weak explanation. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine uses python 2.7, int and long are unified in this version.

See  this question for more informations:
[How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long)

I don't really get why you want to convert this number when you have in my opinion no reason to do so.

Comment: When I print this number, they have L string. So I want to remove it using int type.