# What is the size of an int in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is an int in Python 4 bytes? Is there a possibility to have a 64-byte 'long long' like in C++?

Trying to assign a variable:

```
a = 1234567891011121314
```

Gives this error:

> error: can't allocate region

Comment: Works for me in both python 2.7 as well as Python 3.x , Can you please post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Which version of Python? On what platform? Python has arbitrarily large `int`egers (`long` in 2.x), and that assignment works fine for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python manage int and long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long)

Comment: Python can handle much much larger integers than C or C++ out of the box.  Please post version and let us know if you're in a larger chunk of code or working in the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can handle arbitrary int sizes.  The error you have indicates that python is trying to `malloc` more memory, but failed.  You probably have a memory leak somewhere.