# Why can't convert long type to int type

Tags: python, int

This is my code:

```
In [2]: a = 11111111111111111111111111

In [3]: a = (int)(a)

In [4]: type(a)
Out[4]: long

In [5]: a = int(a)

In [6]: type(a)
Out[6]: long
```

Why, after I call `int` on `a`, is its type still `long` and not `int`?

Comment: Why are you concerned by this, just for curiosity? There is no distinction in python 3; there is a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/) that explains both why you get the result you get and how the types are unified.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

> **class int(x=0)** 
>   **class int(x, base=10)**
>
> [...] If the argument is outside the integer range, the function
>   returns a long object instead.

With [PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/), ints and longs were mostly unified. There is little difference between the two types and python automatically converts big numbers to long when necessary. See also [How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long).

Comment: I misunderstand the meaning of int function. I think his role is conver other types to int . when i see the docs i find it would return a long object if arguments outside the integer range. thanks