# Does PyIntObject still in python3.x source code?

Tags: python-3.x

Does `PyIntObject` still in python3.x source code,or has it been replaced by `PyLongObject`? I can't find the code as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3.2/howto/cporting.html (long/int Unification):

> Python 3 has only one integer type, int(). But it actually corresponds to Python 2’s long() type–the int() type used in Python 2 was removed. In the C-API, PyInt_* functions are replaced by their PyLong_* equivalents.

The best course of action here is using the PyInt_* functions aliased to PyLong_* found in intobject.h. The abstract PyNumber_* APIs can also be used in some cases.

Please check also the following discussion:
[How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long/38544599)