# numpy random choice returning floating numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random

In my code, I randomly generate indices of a large numpy array using the code

```
import numpy as np
random = np.random.RandomState(seed=1000)

r = 140000
c = 30000
k = 210000000
flat_indx = random.choice(xrange(r*c),k,replace=False)
```

But it returns floating number and because of that my code for unravel fails

```
Indx = np.unravel_index(flat_indx,(U,I))
```

I checked the type of the returned array and it is

> type 'numpy.float64'

thought U and I are np.unit64.

This is what I got when I tried it on python shell

```
> random.choice(xrange(140000*30000),10,replace=False) array([2.63189959e+09, 9.52388615e+08, 2.79972090e+09, 1.66392341e+09,
>        3.96565768e+09, 4.18275392e+09, 2.18902320e+07, 2.54430836e+09,
>        1.52407003e+08, 3.36787629e+09])
```

How can I get it corrected ?

Comment: Have you tried `.astype(int)`?

Comment: it is not giving you floating numbers. The numbers are of the order of `1e9`

Comment: @learner, then why unravel_index gives me error about floating number converting to int ?

Comment: @Shew it is mostly because the datatype int overflows and can't accommodate the value. Python internally converts it into float to store such huge values. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long) for more information

Comment: I assume you're on Windows. What version of NumPy are you using?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I am on Linux, and I mostly work on archlinux