# How to check an integer in 32 bit environment in python

Tags: python, integer-overflow

I am solving leetcode problem [7 reverse integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/)

with condition `Assume the environment does not allow you to store 64-bit integers (signed or unsigned).`

Below is my code

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        if x
        val = 0
        pro, x = (1,x) if x>0 else (-1, -x)
        flag = False
        while x:
            val=val*10+x%10
            x//=10
            if val.bit_length()>31:
                flag = True
                break
        return 0 if flag else val*pro
```

code work fine and solve this challenge.

But i am still in doubt and it is related to integer overflow.

considering a strict environment 32 bit, where we need to reverse a number in that range, so if we have a reverse of a number which doesn't fit in 32 bit range, so it will get outflow or not stored(don't know correct terminology, correct me here) so how can we check that part ?

in simple term (i assume), in 32 bit system `val.bit_length()` should be restrict to 31 bits and new int which is adding to the val doesn't add any value to it and it remain same.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it's a bit hard to understand what are you asking for. Python's ints are stored on a heap (at least in CPython), which means there is no int size limit as long as there is enough space to store it. It's implemented internally. See [How does Python manage int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104884/how-does-python-manage-int-and-long) Although if you need real `int32`, you can get it from `mypy` library.

In comparison, in C int is fixed. In case you try to store a value out of boundaries the integer overflow will occur. The C standard defines this situation as undefined behavior (meaning that anything might happen).